# Scala - Pattern Matching for particular fields on a case class?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Let's say I have a case class like this

```
case class CompanyInput(maybeField1: Option[field1], maybeField2: Option[field2], maybeField3: Option[field3], maybeUserTimeZoneId: Option[ZoneId], capabilities: Vector[CompanyCapability])
```

And I want to check that `maybeField1` , `maybeField2` and `maybeField3` are set and optional.... Changing the fields from option to not option is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can use type-specific patterns to compose a bigger pattern and also mark fields irrelevant for a particular branch as underscores

```
  val companyInput = ???
  companyInput match {
    case CompanyInput(Some(field1), Some(field2), Some(field3), _, _) => ???
  }
```